# Norm inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-analysis, norms

In an article I read, I have the following inequality:
$\|A-B\|_1 \geq \max \{ \|A 1_m- B 1_m \|_1, \|A^T 1_n - B^T1_n\|_1 \}$

Where $A, B \in \mathbb{R}_+^{m\times n}$.
The $\|\cdot\|_1$ refers either to the $l_1$ vector norm, either to the matrix operator norm.
They use Jensen inequality for this result.

This result seems wrong in general, we can take $A = I_2$ and $B = 0$ to show it.
I was wondering under what hypotheses this inequality is true.
Is it the case for bistochastic matrices ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality is true if $\|A - B\|_1$ is interpreted as $\sum |A_{ij} - B_{ij}|$.

Just observe that
$$ \|A 1_M - B 1_M\|_1 = \sum_i | \sum_j A_{ij} - B_{ij}| \leq \sum_i \sum_j |A_{ij} - B_{ij}| $$
by the triangle inequality.